# Change the condition based on the above row value for the same id sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am developing a logic that requires a change in condition based on the above row of a column , the common is it shares the same ID

**Current Sample**

| ID | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 | Column6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | M1AGE | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | NB1HOH | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 17 | M1AGE | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 17 | NB1HOH | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 17 | NB1WORK | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 39 | F3AGE | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 39 | NB3HOH | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 25 | M1AGE | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 25 | NB1HOH | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 25 | NB1WORK | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 26 | NB1WORK | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 26 | NB2HOH | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 26 | M1AGE | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 26 | F2AGE | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |

**REQUIRED OUTPUT**

| ID | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 | Column6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | M1AGE | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | M1HOH | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 17 | M1AGE | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 17 | M1HOH | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 17 | M1WORK | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 39 | F3AGE | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 39 | F3HOH | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 25 | M1AGE | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 25 | M1HOH | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 25 | M1WORK | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 26 | M1WORK | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 26 | F2HOH | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 26 | M1AGE | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 26 | F2AGE | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |

```
update #results
set Column2= REPLACE(Column2, 'NB', 'F')
from #results
where Column5= 2
  and Column2 like '%NB[1-9]AGE%'

update #results
set Column2= REPLACE(Column2, 'NB', 'M')
from #results
where Column5= 1
  and Column2 like '%NB[1-9]AGE%'
```

The logic is if any row has `'%F[1-9]AGE%'` and `Column6 =2` then the Question for the same Id has to be automatically assigned as `'%F[1-9]WORK%'` and `'%F[1-9]HOH%'`

Same for `M`

The logic is if any row has `'%M[1-9]AGE%'` and `Column6 =1` then the Question for the same Id has to be automatically assigned as `'%M[1-9]WORK%'` and `'%M[1-9]HOH%'`

I tried this query

```
update #results
set Column2 = REPLACE(r.Column2, 'NB', 'F')
from #results r
where R.Column2 NOT LIKE '%F[1-9]AGE%'
  AND r.Column2 LIKE '%NB[1-9]WORK%'
   OR r.Column2 LIKE '%NB[1-9]HOH%'
  AND R.id = id
```

Comment: Please do not paste images of code or data, please paste in sample data and expected results as text only.

Comment: can you show example data and expected with text? Can you explain more?. I mean, you want such a query
 set Column2 = case  when Column2 like  '%M[1-9]AGE%' and content =1  then  REPLACE(r.Column2, 'NB', 'F') when Column2   like '%F[1-9]AGE%' and content =2   then   REPLACE(Column2, 'NB', 'M') end
They are hardcoded or they have to read from other records

Comment: @abolfazlsadeghi  they have to be read from other records

Comment: You mention column `content` in your description below but I see no column of that name. Besides that I'm finding your logic VERY hard to follow. You say *"then the Question for the same Id has to be automatically assigned as '%F[1-9]WORK%' and '%F[1-9]HOH%'"* < What is a "question" and it gets "Automatically assigned" what exactly? I see `column 6` gets value `2` for id `6`... why? Nothing in your description suggests why it would be `2` or why we are updating only `column 6`. Please clarify.

Comment: Logic doesn't make sense: The second row has `Column6 : 2` and yet you are setting that row from the one above which is `Column6 : 1` which does't fit your described logic. Please better describe *in words* what you want to happen, and why. For example why is the third-last row set to `F2HOH` and not `M2HOH`

Comment: Its Column6 instead of content ,i have corrected... If one of the row contents= M[1-9]Age and column6=1 for id=(some value) e.g 6 ,and the other rows are still nbwork or nbhoh then those values have to be also assigned to M1HOH and M1WORK,its the same for F[1-9]Age and column6=2 for id=(some value) e.g 7 ,and the other rows are still nbwork or nbhoh @JNevill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Common Table Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
-- Create a temporary table
CREATE TABLE #results
(
    ID INT,
    Column2 NVARCHAR(50),
    Column3 INT,
    Column4 INT,
    Column5 INT,
    Column6 INT
)

-- Insert sample data
INSERT INTO #results
(ID, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, Column6)
VALUES
(6, 'M1AGE', 1, 1, 1, 1),
(6, 'NB1HOH', 1, 1, 1, 2),
(17, 'M1AGE', 1, 1, 1, 1),
(17, 'NB1HOH', 1, 1, 1, 1),
(17, 'NB1WORK', 1, 1, 1, 3),
(39, 'F3AGE', 1, 1, 1, 2),
(39, 'NB3HOH', 1, 1, 1, 2),
(25, 'M1AGE', 1, 1, 1, 1),
(25, 'NB1HOH', 1, 1, 1, 2),
(25, 'NB1WORK', 1, 1, 1, 0),
(26, 'NB1WORK', 1, 1, 1, 2),
(26, 'NB2HOH', 1, 1, 1, 2),
(26, 'M1AGE', 1, 1, 1, 1),
(26, 'F2AGE', 1, 1, 1, 2);

-- Update the table based on the given conditions
WITH AgeRows AS (
    SELECT ID, Column6, SUBSTRING(Column2, 1, 1) AS Gender
    FROM #results
    WHERE Column2 LIKE '%[MF][1-9]AGE%'
),
UpdateRows AS (
    SELECT r.ID, r.Column2, r.Column6, a.Gender
    FROM #results r
    JOIN AgeRows a ON r.ID = a.ID
    WHERE r.Column2 LIKE '%NB[1-9]WORK%' OR r.Column2 LIKE '%NB[1-9]HOH%'
)
UPDATE r
SET Column2 = REPLACE(r.Column2, 'NB', u.Gender)
FROM #results r
JOIN UpdateRows u ON r.ID = u.ID AND r.Column2 = u.Column2;

-- Select the updated data
SELECT * FROM #results;

-- Drop the temporary table
DROP TABLE #results;
```

| ID | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 | Column6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | M1AGE | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | M1HOH | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 17 | M1AGE | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 17 | M1HOH | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 17 | M1WORK | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 39 | F3AGE | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 39 | F3HOH | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 25 | M1AGE | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 25 | M1HOH | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 25 | M1WORK | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 26 | M1WORK | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 26 | M2HOH | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 26 | M1AGE | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 26 | F2AGE | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GhP2MPR_)